# javascript - name or id of element

Tags: javascript

Is `this.form.sel2` similar to `document.getElementById('sel2')`?

My select tag is as follows:

```
<select size=5 id="sub_player_ids" name="sub[player_ids][]">
```

And when I am putting the name of the tag, i.e, `sub[player_ids][]` in my javascript code, am getting a syntax error. 
I am trying to find a workaround so that instead of using the name of the element, i want to use the id.

However using `document.getElementById('sub_player_ids')` is not working.

Thanks for any suggestion provided.

Please see my javascript code below:

```
      <input type="button" value="--&gt;"
       onclick="moveOptions(this.form.sel1, this.form.sel2);" /><br />
      <input type="button" value="&lt;--"
       onclick="moveOptions(this.form.sel2, this.form.sel1);" />
```

Comment: `aForm["complexFormElementName"]` (or `aForm.simpleFormElementName`) -- id's need to apply, although some browsers like IE *may* work with them.

Comment: I don't see any element with ID or name of `sel2`. What gives?

Comment: Your id is "sub_player_ids", why are you trying to get 'sel2'?

Comment: This will help you. http://www.baytree-cs.com/combo-select-box.html you can give only ID in getElementById

Comment: `getElementById` works well and consistently. There is no element with the id `sel2` in the above code so it's hard to say why it may (or may not) be working as expected.

Comment: sorry i guys..my fault, can't believe i missed that

Comment: @pst: *"`getElementById` works well and consistently"* Mostly, yeah -- except on IE7 and earlier, where IE will happily return you an element that doesn't have an `id` at all but does have that `name` (IE7 and below conflates `id` and `name`, even with `getElementById`), even when there's an element lower down on the page that actually does have the `id`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Very true. I was assuming the *positive* matching case in the previous statement, and not the erroneous case of returning something without said id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` of your element is `sub_player_ids`, not `sel2`. So `document.getElementById("sub_player_ids")` would work.

You may also find that `this.form["sub[player_ids][]"]` would work. Using the quoted form lets you use things that you can't use in the literal form.

Something to beware of is that IE7 and earlier have a broken version of `getElementById` that will find things that use the given string as a `name`, rather than as an `id`, even if something later on the page actually uses it as an `id`. (Yes, really; [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html).) Some libraries will work around that for you ([jQuery](http://jquery.com) does, for instance). And actually, speaking of libraries, a good library really can help work around all sorts of browser inconsistencies and provide a lot of handy utility functionality, letting you concentrate on your actual business problems. You might consider looking at [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Answer (score 2):

You can use bracket notation instead:

```
this.form['sub[player_ids][]']
```

...or `getElementById()`, with the *right* ID:

```
document.getElementById('sub_player_ids')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById('sub_player_ids')` to get that element.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong id

```
document.getElementById('sub_player_ids')
```

Answer (score 1):

verify that your options contains `id`, it would only be containing `name` with `sel2`